# macOS Sonoma : Your computer was restarted because of a problem

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

Since last night, my MBA M1 is restarting whenever left idle or on sleep. Eventually it shows this error - Your computer was restarted because of a problem.
I used LuLu and Firewall to make Photoshop crack work and panic report started after enabling LuLu. I've removed all the adobe and LuLu applications but still getting crash reports.

I'm getting Panic reports which are posted below. I even ran EtreCheck and report is posted below.
"kernel extensions in backtrace” is Kernel Extensions in backtrace: com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(404.0).

```
>  panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe0014b0bc50): [kalloc.type.var6.128]:
> element modified after free (off:88, val:0x00000000ffffffff, sz:128,
> ptr:0xfffffe20187c0980)    88: 0x00000000ffffffff Debugger message:
> panic Memory ID: 0xff OS release type: User OS version: 23B81 Kernel
> version: Darwin Kernel Version 23.1.0: Mon Oct  9 21:28:12 PDT 2023;
> root:xnu-10002.41.9~6/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103

  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall(404.0)[1BB9F8E2-4963-3A2E-9B39-E227D659C008]@0xfffffe0014bf1370->0xfffffe0014bf7a13
```

EtreCheck Report :

```
 EtreCheckPro version: 6.8.4 (68040)
Report generated: 2024-02-05 15:35:09
Download EtreCheckPro from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 2:45
Performance: Excellent

Problem: Computer is restarting

Major Issues:
  Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention. 
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed that could be malicious and should be reviewed.
  Kernel panics - This system has experienced kernel panics. This could be a sign of hardware failure.

Minor Issues:
  These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement. 
  Apps crashing - There have been numerous app crashes.
  Clean up - There are orphan files that could be removed.
  Limited permissions - More information may be available with Full Disk Access.
  Kernel extensions present - This computer has kernel extensions that may not work in the future.

Hardware Information:
  MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
    Status: Supported
  MacBook Air Model: MacBookAir10,1
  2.40 GHz Apple M1 (m1) CPU: 8-core
  8 GB RAM - Not upgradeable
  Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 94

Video Information:
  Apple M1
    Color LCD (built-in) 2880 x 1800

Drives:
  disk0 - APPLE SSD AP0256Q 251.00 GB (Solid State - TRIM: Yes) 
  Internal Apple Fabric NVM Express
    disk0s1 [APFS Container] 524 MB
      disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 524 MB (Shared by 4 volumes)
        disk1s1 - iSCPreboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (6 MB used)
        disk1s2 - xART (APFS) (6 MB used)
        disk1s3 - Hardware (APFS) (643 KB used)
        disk1s4 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (20 KB used)
    disk0s2 [APFS Container] 245.11 GB
      disk3 [APFS Virtual drive] 245.11 GB (Shared by 6 volumes)
        disk3s1 (APFS) [APFS Container] (13.46 GB used)
          disk3s1s1 - Macintosh HD (APFS) [APFS Snapshot] (13.46 GB used)
        disk3s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (11.57 GB used)
        disk3s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (1.81 GB used)
        disk3s4 - Update (APFS) (667 MB used)
        disk3s5 - Data (APFS) [APFS Virtual drive] (102.43 GB used)
        disk3s6 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (20 KB used)
    disk0s3 [APFS Container] 5.37 GB
      disk2 [APFS Virtual drive] 5.37 GB (Shared by 2 volumes)
        disk2s1 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (1.60 GB used)
        disk2s2 - Update (APFS) (29 KB used)


Security:
  Gatekeeper: App Store and identified developers
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Secure Boot: Full Security

  Antivirus software: Apple

Unsigned Files:
  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.EdgeUpdater.update.system.plist
    Command: /Library/Microsoft/EdgeUpdater/109.0.1518.107/EdgeUpdater.app/Contents/MacOS/EdgeUpdater --server --service=update --enable-logging --vmodule=*/components/update_client/*=2,*/chrome/updater/*=2 --system



Diagnostics Information (past 60 days):
  2024-02-05 14:26:09 Kernel Panic
    Details:
      panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe0014b0bc50): [kalloc.type.var6.128]: elemen
      t modified after free (off:88, val:0x00000000ffffffff, sz:128, ptr:0xf
      ffffe20187c0980)
      Panicked task 0xfffffe1b4ac45048: 1448 pages, 7 threads: pid 2231: gam
      ed


  2024-02-05 10:42:40 fileproviderd High CPU Use
    First occurrence: 2024-02-05 10:44:23
    Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Support/fileproviderd

  2024-02-05 09:38:44 Console Crash
    Executable: /System/Applications/Utilities/Console.app
    Details:
      libdispatch.dylib: API MISUSE: Over-release of an object

  2024-02-05 09:35:05 Adobe Desktop Service Crash (2 times)
    First occurrence: 2024-02-04 19:30:35

  2024-02-04 21:57:39 Kernel Panic
    Details:
      panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe00150cbc50): [kalloc.type.var4.128]: elemen
      t modified after free (off:88, val:0x00000000ffffffff, sz:128, ptr:0xf
      ffffe208bce8180)
      Panicked task 0xfffffe33be4bb9b8: 3553 pages, 10 threads: pid 465: Con
      trolCenter


  2024-02-04 20:05:23 knowledgeconstructiond High CPU Use (2 times)
    First occurrence: 2024-02-04 20:07:17
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IntelligencePlatformCore.framework/Versions/A/knowledgeconstructiond

  2024-02-03 23:54:46 iOSScreenCaptureAssistant Crash (14 times)
    First occurrence: 2024-02-01 02:07:59
    Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/iOSScreenCapture.plugin
    Details:
      libdispatch.dylib: API MISUSE: Resurrection of an object

  2024-02-03 16:39:59 Google Chrome.app High CPU Use
    First occurrence: 2024-02-03 16:42:58
    Executable: /Applications/Google Chrome.app

  2024-02-02 14:15:32 coreaudiod Crash (2 times)
    Executable: /usr/sbin/coreaudiod

  2024-02-01 02:12:09 mds_stores Crash (2 times)
    Executable: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores


End of report
```

I couldn't upload complete crash report as my post was getting flagged as spam. If required I can share it over cloud.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not running the most recent version of macOS? Would update to 14.3 first and see whether the problem persists.

Comment: I'm updating it to 14.3 now. I assumed it might be not due to 14.2 as changed firewall settings through LuLu for the photoshop crack.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning in the question that you use Lulu. And of course, if the problem persists, disabling Lulu is a good next analysis step.

Comment: My bad, edited the post. I have uninstalled LuLu, Adobe CC and PS but I still got Kernel panic again. Thus I'm not able to isolate it. Problem did start after changing firewall settings/lulu